# Cannot see Workplace Switcher in the Activities screen in Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, compiz, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 20.04 with windows on my laptop. The Workspace switcher panel usually present on the right side in the activities or launchpad screen is completely gone. I can still use Ctrl+Alt+arrows to switch workspaces but I can't see how many or which workspaces are existing. I have enabled horizontal workspaces.

I was going for a MacOS look on my ubuntu desktop and installed the theme, icon, cursor etc and applied it through gnome-tweaks. Workspace setting is set to Dynamic Workspaces in gnome-tweaks.

I installed some compiz packages as well looking for the solution and have fiddled with a few settings in the compizconfig settings but nothing seems to change anyway. I don't know how to enable compiz also. I am using the default Ubuntu desktop as of now.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Compiz? Why did you install compiz? Are you using the default Ubuntu desktop or another? How did you enable horizontal workspaces? Add usefull information to the problem in your question itself: use "edit". Comments may not be read or may dissappear.

Comment: Maybe this https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-cannot-find-workspaces-in-ubuntu-20-04/ can help; I hope I understood your question well.

Comment: @vanadium as I said I was searching for solutions and somehow I ended up on compiz. Yes I am using the default Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: So you cannot be using compiz. Better remove that tag not to confuse people looking to help. Also remove any reference to compiz in your post: as you see yourself, you can install and configure it, but it does not apply to the default desktop, which is based on Gnome Shell. Check your customizations. One of these will be the cause of the problem.